# echo font color output

Tags: php, colors, echo

I wrote a php code that display error in red color. But somehow, this doesn't seem to work out. Here's my code:

```
<?php
...    
if(!$name || !$email || !$contact || !$itemid){
                        //if not display an error message
                        echo "<span style="color: red;" /><center>Fields marked with <strong>&#40; &#42; &#421</strong> are mandatory!</center></span>";
                        }else{...


?>
```

Comment: You might see the problem if you look at the source of the HTML page that is being output. This is meant as a troubleshooting tip.

Comment: this should give an error to start with. fix it.

Comment: You're right, no need to look at the source, it's right on the page if error reporting is on. Looks like this: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'` which helps troubleshoot by telling you the problem.

Comment: Thanks. Will keep that in mind from now on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this something like that --

```
echo '<span style="color: red;" /><center>Fields marked with <strong>&#40; &#42; &#421</strong> are mandatory!</center></span>';
```

Your `""` quotes are conflicting

Answer (score 2):

```
    <?php
...    
if(!$name || !$email || !$contact || !$itemid){
                        //if not display an error message
                        echo "<span style='color: red;' /><center>Fields marked with <strong>&#40; &#42; &#421</strong> are mandatory!</center></span>";
                        }else{...


?>
```

try this
you were closing the quotations

Comment: Could you please explain your answer, so that the OP can know where and what was wrong in his code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is un-escaped quotes on your PHP expression.

```
echo "<span style="color: red;" />...
                //^ Right here
```

Because, Your PHP `echo` statement also started with the same quote i.e `"`.

Here are the different ways you can solve this:

1. Use mixed quotes

   ```
   echo "<span style='color: red;' />...
         // Single quote in the HTML part
   ```
2. Escape the quotes

   ```
   echo "<span style=\"color: red;\" />...
        // Escape the quotes so that it gets treated as string rather than a modifier
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You are generating invalid HTML. A `<span>` element cannot contain a `<center>` element. Browsers may error correct by moving the `<center>` element so it is outside the `<span>` (so the style rules applied to the span won't inheit into the `<center>` element).

Generate valid markup (and move your style rules to a stylesheet).

```
echo "<p class='error'>Fields marked with <strong>&#40; &#42; &#421</strong> are mandatory!</p>";
```

Comment: Technically, no, but I'm sure that wasn't what was causing his problem.

Comment: the <center> tag is also deprecated even in html 4.0; consider using "text-align:center" in css.

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes are conflicting. Either escape them, or use single and double quotes

```
 echo '<span style="color: red;" /><center>Fields marked with <strong>&#40; &#42; &#421</strong> are mandatory!</center></span>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify with single quotes in color attr and remove 'center' also,
 `echo "<span style='color: red;' />`